# Decrypting passwords stored in ASP application during migration to Node.js

Tags: node.js, asp.net, asp.net-core, encryption, passwords

I would like guidance on how to properly decrypt the passwords in Node.js and ensure their security during the migration process. Here are my specific questions:

How can I identify the encryption algorithm used in the ASP application to ensure compatibility in the Node.js environment?
What steps should I follow to securely retrieve the encryption key used in the ASP application?
What considerations should I keep in mind when decrypting passwords to ensure their security during the migration process?
Are there any best practices or security precautions I should follow when handling the decrypted passwords in Node.js before storing them in the new database?
Should I inform the users about the migration and prompt them to update their passwords? If so, what would be the recommended approach?
Any guidance, code snippets, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. I want to ensure that I handle this sensitive information properly and follow the best practices for secure password migration during the ASP to Node.js migration process.

Thank you in advance for your help!